# Working with intent data when dealing with several activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have several activities which are are linked together. There are : `Activity_1 -> Activity_2 -> Activity_3` where activity 1 is the parent of activity 2 and activity 2 is parent of activity 3. The manifest is as follow:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_1"
...>
<activity android:name=".Activity_2">
     <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
       android:value=".activities.Activity_1" />
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Activity_3">
     <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".activities.Activity_2" />

</activity>
```

in `Activity_1` adapter I send some data to `Activity_2` via onclick listener (through the adapter) :

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity_2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title",title.getText());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

and in `Activity_2` I retrieve that data:

```
....
private String title;
....
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
     title = extras.getString("title");
   }
   ...
   // some important usage of title here
```

I have another onclick listener that goes from activity 2 to activity 3 and when I click on the back button, the app crashes because title is returned `null`.

I dont want to use preferences to store the title, any idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are fetching info from the intent during `onResume` which is called from Activity1 -> Activity2 and also in the way back from Activity3 -> Activity2.

You may want to consider doing so during `onCreate` instead.
Does that make sense?

EDIT: So... I just learnt that navigation up (the "<-" on the action bar) is different from navigation back (hard button).
You can solve this issue using different approaches:

- [Make your activity "singleTop"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342137/1231880)
- [Intercept "navigation up" and turn it into "navigation back"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22947847/1231880)

Comment: thanks for your comment but I am getting the indent data during `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the context from the `View` you should get the `Activity` Context. Try instead of this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity_2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title",title.getText());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title",title.getText());
                    this.startActivity(intent);
```

actually when your in an activity you could also just do `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: The intent is called in my adapter and not the activity, I updated the question

Comment: which part is unclear? I can modify the question if necessary